# How do I replace a Qt 4.8 QWidget with a QTabWidget in Qt Designer

Tags: qt, qt4, qt-designer

I'd like to replace my QWidget central widget and all its contents with a QTabWidget with the same contents.  Is there an easy way to do this in Qt Designer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select all widgets you want to move, then right click and select **cut**, place QTab widget and press **CTRL+V**, or you can select **CTRL+A** then **CTRL+X**, place a QTab widget then finally press **CTRL+V**.